# What is the error when approximating $L^2([0,1])$ by a finite dimensional space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Let $X \subset L^2([0,1])$ such that $f([0,1]) \subset [-M,M]$, for some constant $M$, and any $f \in X$.
By choosing a finite dimensional basis $V=\left(v_i\right)_{i=0}^n$,
where each $v_i \in X$, form the space $X_n = \mathrm{span}\left(V\right)$.
How to determine the error of the approximation
$$
\max_{f \in X} \|f -  \sum \left(f,v_i\right) v_i \| , \tag{1}
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^2$ norm, and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^2$ inner product.

For the basis functions $v_i$, I'm considering:
- piecewise polynomial function,
like is done in finite element method; or,
- truncated Fourier series.
But other basis can also do, if they deliver (1) more easily.

I ask because I want to numerically explore the space $X$.
But the approximation $X_n$ should be sufficiently good so as to catch the important behavior of $X$.

If you can point to some reference where (1) is calculated, or highlight the general procedure, it will help.

Comment: Do you mean $\max\{ \|f - g\| : g \in X_n\}$ or something to that effect?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan For my understanding, the error is in the orthogonal space. If I use your formula, the error will be too big: for any $f$, the closest $g \in X_n$ to $f$ is $\sum (f,v_i) v_i$, I think.

Comment: Then you want $\min\{\|f-g\| : g\in X_n\}$. What you have written is taking a max over a bunch of vectors, which does not make sense.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I see, I miswrite the max notation. I have corrected it, is it better now?

Comment: You probably want to normalize it : Otherwise just take $f_k\in X_n^{\perp}$ with $\|f_k\| = k$ and this quantity blows up. In any case, taking a max over all $f \in X$ seems like an awfully large thing to try to minimize.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Yes, thank you. I forgot to say that $X$ contains only bounded function. I added it.

Comment: Unless you assume a lot more about $X$ than the bounded range, you are likely to find that (1) is equal to $\max_{f\in X}\|f\|$. Indeed, this is the case for *every* finite dimensional $V$, if $X$ contains all functions with values in $[-M,M]$.